# Why django_migrations table is created even though router does not allow migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have `'default'` and `'secondary'` databases. Why, even though it is stated:

```
makemigrations always creates migrations for model changes, but if allow_migrate() returns False, any migration operations for the model_name will be silently skipped when running migrate on the db. Changing the behavior of allow_migrate() for models that already have migrations may result in broken foreign keys, extra tables, or missing tables. When makemigrations verifies the migration history, it skips databases where no app is allowed to migrate.
```

when running `./manage.py migrate --database=secondary` I receive all the migrations listed as OK and `django_migrations` table existing in the `'secondary'` database, instead of no migrations and no trace for them. Is it a Django design decision or I messed up the routing?

```
class PrimaryRouter:
    """Primary router allowing ORM operations only on default database"""

    # NOTE: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_set = {'default'}
        if obj1._state.db in db_set and obj2._state.db in db_set:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """

        return db == 'default'


# settings
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app.routers.PrimaryRouter', ]
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895063/why-is-django-migrations-table-in-all-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this was intentional as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate)

> makemigrations always creates migrations for model changes, but if
> allow_migrate() returns False, any migration operations for the
> model_name will be silently skipped

So that would mean that only [migration operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#module-django.db.migrations.operations) will be skipped

Comment: Thank you for that. Needed to make sure so I don't mess my dbs up.